# How to play call waiting beep sound when a second call comes to my iOS voip app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pjsip, callkit

I'm building an iOS voip app using PJSip library. I am using CallKit also. During an active call, if another call comes, the call waiting screen with hold & accept, end & accept.. is shown. But there is no beep sound so that the user can get notified that a new call is coming. I want to make that beep sound some how. Somebody please help.

Comment: Did you ever make any progress on this one? I'm stuck with the same issue. Not only that, but attempts to play sounds out-of-band fail when the CallKit UI is showing.

Comment: I have following this link but error in opening file .     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19047771/ios-pjsip-play-a-sound-during-sip-call?rq=1 .   Please help

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by just add some audio configuration when second call comes and then there will be beeping sound come up. This is worked for me.

```
extension CallManager: CXCallObserverDelegate {

    func callObserver(_ CallObserver: CallObserver: CXCallObserver, callChanged call: CXCall) {
        if call.uuid != firstcall {
            configureAudioSession()
        }
    }
}

func configureAudioSession() {
    print("Configuring audio session")
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: [.mixWithOthers])
        try session.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat)
    } catch (let error) {
        print("Error while configuring audio session: \(error)")
    }
}
```